# How to mock Firestore v9 getDocs() with Jest

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, mocking, react-testing-library, ts-jest

We recently upgraded our webapp from Firebase v8 to v9, and got all kind of problems from the new syntax. I am still quite new to Jest and Firebase/Firestore, so not everything is crystal clear to me yet ...

I am trying to mock `getDocs` from `firebase/firestore` because I get this error message:

```
      TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'docs')
          at /.../src/.../operations.ts:123:45
          at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:34:5)
          at Object.<anonymous> (/.../src/.../index.test.ts:1234:6)
```

The error happens when testing gets into the following code:

```
const firestoreInstance = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
...
      const dataList = query(
        getDataCollection(),
        where('id', 'in', idList)
      )
      const dataDict: { [key: string]: {id: string, name: string} } = {}
      ;(await getDocs(dataList)).docs.forEach(
        (dataItem) => {
          const data = dataItem.data()
          dataDict[data['id']].name = data.name
        }
      )
```

Where `getDataCollection` is someting like:

```
export const getDataCollection = (): CollectionReference  =>
  collection(
    firestoreInstance,
    `path-to-collection`
  )
```

Because getDocs is not mocked. If I mock `getDocs` like this:

```
    ;(getDocs as any).mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({
      docs: {
        data: () => ({
          name: 'name-for-this-data-item',
        }),
      },
    }))
```

I get the following error in the Jest output for this test:

```
TypeError: _firestore.getDocs.mockImplementation is not a function
```

Mocking Firebase v9 seems to be hard from all the unanswered questions I have seen on the internet and I did not find any direct answer to my problem.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong? And any pointer to how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often, I hesitate to ask questions here, and when I do, I often end up finding an answer myself soon after ...

So to put it simply: no need to mock `getDocs`!

Instead, the mock for the collection get function had to be modified from:

```
   ;(getDataCollection as any).mockImplementation(() => ({
      docs: {
        data: () => ({
          name: 'name-for-this-data-item',
        }),
      },
    }))
```

To:

```
    ;(getDataCollection as any).mockImplementation(() => ({
      query: {
        docs:[{
          data: () => ({
            id: 'id-for-this-data-item',
            name: 'name-for-this-data-item',
          }),
        }],
      },
    }))
  })
```

To add a level for the `query` function.

I also added an `id` field in the data to correct a second UNRELATED error in my algorithm.

I hope that helps other Jest/Firebase/Firestore newbies like me.